# Start an angular 8 application

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

Good evening,

I am taking a course on udemy on angular 8 I am always beginner, I follow all the instructions of the teacher to start an angular application namely the creation of boot files tsconfig, package.json .... all the codes put in his files I took them from the git of the teacher of the course angular here is the link :
[git of the teacher](https://gist.github.com/moumoune/4823306afa00b6b873243fc18dd247e0)

The problem is when I put the command npm start in my command to start my application it does not work here are the errors I had:

[image: error angular]

here is the structure of my files if needed:

[image: all fichier]

Someone can help me please ???!

Comment: This is not an angular project ... ?

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial might be a better starting point..

Comment: yes it is a angular project

Comment: In it’s current structure it is not an Angular project. Post your package.json and your angular.json files.

Comment: Did you leave a question in the course for Simon or others taking the course to answer? That is usually the best place to get an answer on specific code in a course.

Comment: yes I have already done but no response, but after some research I managed to solve the problem thank you all